# How to get every 1st and 4th line using notepad++ regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am very new to regular expressions and I have some 20k lines in a text file following a specific format. Example below

```
  To:  1234@abc.com
  From: 5678@abc.com
  Message-info: hshjsjsjjsjdjdjsjjsj
  Subject: email regarding
                   Your new house
```

I need ‘To: ‘ and ‘Subject:’ lines to be copy and pasted a new editor.

I have used ‘bookmark lines’ option in notepad++ for both To and Subject separately but the total number is not matching.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I recommend [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116328/regexp-matching-string-not-starting-with-my), and use search and replace everything NOT matching your regex with NOTHING (empty string) .... (basically Notepad++ regex should word like "regular" regex :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there is 2 space characters at the beginning of each line. Try using regex:

```
^  (?!To:|Subject:).*$\r*\n*
```

and replace it with nothing (empty string)

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bhvcGu/1)