# Regex for strings not starting with "My" or "By"

Tags: regex, re2

I need Regex which matches when my string does not start with "MY" and "BY".

I have tried something like:

```
r = /^my&&^by/
```

but it doesn't work for me

eg

> mycountry = false ; byyou = false ; xyz = true ;

Comment: Give few test cases for your string !

Comment: use `string.startWith('my') || string.startsWith('by')`

Comment: @Tushar updated

Comment: @pro.mean You definitely should write that as an answer.

Comment: I'm genuinely curious about the answer to this as I'm not certain how to do a double-negative.  While @pro.mean's response is valid javascript, it does not answer the question of how to do it using a regular expression.  The vote to "close" means the voter did not actually read the question as the ask is very clear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegExp matching string not starting with my](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116328/regexp-matching-string-not-starting-with-my)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could test if the string does not start with `by` or `my`, case insensitive.

```js
var r = /^(?!by|my)/i;

console.log(r.test('My try'));
console.log(r.test('Banana'));
```

without `!`

```js
var r = /^([^bm][^y]|[bm][^y]|[^bm][y])/i;

console.log(r.test('My try'));
console.log(r.test('Banana'));
console.log(r.test('xyz'));
```

Comment: Your Regex is case sensitive......Ashutosh Jha ask to detect "by" or "my".

Comment: ! is not supported by RE2

Comment: I need it in google analytics API which demand RE2 syntex 
https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax

Answer (score 0):

if you are only concerned with only specific text at the start of the string than you can use latest js string method [.startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)

```
  let str = "mylove";

  if(str.startsWith('my') || str.startsWith('by')) {
    // handle this case
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try This(Regex is NOT case sensitive):**

```js
  var r = /^([^bm][y])/i; //remove 'i' for case sensitive("by" or "my")

console.log('mycountry = '+r.test('mycountry'));
console.log('byyou= '+r.test('byyou'));
console.log('xyz= '+r.test('xyz'));

console.log('Mycountry = '+r.test('Mycountry '));
console.log('Byyou= '+r.test('Byyou'));

console.log('MYcountry = '+r.test('MYcountry '));
console.log('BYyou= '+r.test('BYyou'));
```

Comment: ! is not supported by RE2

Comment: I need it in google analytics API which demand RE2 syntex 
https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax

Comment: @AshutoshJha i changed it to support RE2!